# Iran's list of designated terrorist organizations?

Tags: policy, terrorism, iran

[In 2007, according to CNN:](http://edition.cnn.com/2007/WORLD/meast/09/29/iran.parliament/)

> The Iranian parliament on Saturday voted to designate the United States' Central Intelligence Agency and the U.S. Army as terrorist organizations, IRNA, the country's state-run news agency, reported.

I unfortunately could not find the IRNA press release ([the IRNA web archive](http://en.irna.ir/Archive.aspx?vwc=161&part=11&Page=120) returns an error at the 121th page).

Does Iran have an "official list of designated terrorist organizations", like [Australia](http://www.nationalsecurity.gov.au/agd/WWW/NationalSecurity.nsf/Page/What_Governments_are_doingListing_of_Terrorism_Organisations) and [others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations)?

If yes, where can it be seen? (preferably online)

Answer (score 1):

The 121st page can now be opened.

Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_designated_terrorist_organizations) will help you, but I bet the top of the Iran's Official list of designated terrorists organizations will be Israel, followed by America.

Comment: You should read the wikipedia article. It doesn't list any governments (though it does list some political parties that are also terrorist groups).